# Python Programming difficulty

Tags: python

I have two programs that I'm trying to get to work. twitter.py is suppose to act as a manager for Tweet.py. Twitter adds in new tweets, views the last 5 most recent tweets with the highest unit of time next to it ex:

```
Recent Tweets
------------
Dave - 5min
Hello world!
```

Tweet defines the class Tweet for twitter.py to manage. Tweet class has three data attributes: __author, __age, and __text and four methods: get_author, get_text, and get_age (special because it is suppose to calculate the difference between the current time and value of __age, then return it as string). The third choice should be allowed to search for any keywords among the tweets.

Ex:

```
What would you like to search for? Cat

Search results 
--------------
Daniel - 2hrs

My cat is fluffy.
```

twitter.py - http://pastebin.com/mQ9CCu3H

```
import Tweet
import pickle

MAKE = 1
VIEW = 2
SEARCH = 3
QUIT = 4

FILENAME = 'tweets.dat'

def main():
    mytweets = load_tweets()

    choice = 0

    while choice != QUIT:
        choice = get_menu_choice()

        if choice == MAKE:
            add(mytweets)
        elif choice == VIEW:
            recent(mytweets)
        elif choice == SEARCH:
            find(mytweets)
        else:
            print("\nThanks for using the Twitter manager!")

    save_tweets(mytweets)

def load_tweets():
    try:
        input_file = open(FILENAME, 'rb')

        tweet_dct = pickle.load(input_file)

        input_file.close()

    except IOError:
        tweet_dct = {}

    return tweet_dct

def get_menu_choice():
    print()
    print('Tweet Menu')
    print("----------")
    print("1. Make a Tweet")
    print("2. View Recent Tweets")
    print("3. Search Tweets")
    print("4. Quit")
    print()


    try:
        choice = int(input("What would you like to do? "))
        if choice < MAKE or choice > QUIT:
            print("Please select a valid option./n")

    except ValueError:
        print("Please enter a numeric value. /n")

    return choice

def add(mytweets):

    author = input("\nWhat is your name? ")
    while True:
        text = input("what would you like to tweet? ")
        if len(text) > 140:
            print("\nTweets can only be 140 characters!")
            continue
        else:
            break




    entry = Tweet.Tweet(author, text)

    print("\nYour tweet has been saved!")

def recent(mytweets):
    print("\nRecent Tweets")
    print("---------------")
    if len(mytweets) < 1:
        print("There are no recent tweets.")
    else:
        print(mytweets(-5))

def find(mytweets):


    author = input("What would you like to search for? ")
    if author in mytweets:
        print("\nSearch Results")
        print("----------------")
        print(Tweet.Tweet.get_author, - Tweet.Tweet.get_age)
        print(Tweet.Tweet.get_text)
    else:
        print("\nSearch Results")
        print("----------------")
        print("No tweets contained ", Tweet.Tweet.get_author, Tweet.Tweet.get_text)

def save_tweets(mytweets):
    output_file = open(FILENAME, 'wb')

    pickle.dump(mytweets, output_file)

    output_file.close()

main()
```

Tweet.py - http://pastebin.com/AcmprzAT

```
import time

class Tweet:

    def __init__(self, author, text):

        self.__author = author
        self.__text = text
        self.__age = time.time()

    def get_author(self):

        return self.__author

    def get_text(self):

        return self.__text

    def get_age(self):
        now = time.time()

        difference = now - self.__time

        hours = difference // 3600

        difference = difference % 3600

        minutes = difference // 60

        seconds = difference % 60


        # Truncate units of time and convert them to strings for output
        hours = str(int(hours))
        minutes = str(int(minutes))
        seconds = str(int(seconds))

        # Return formatted units of time
        return hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds
```

The problems I am having:

1. When doing choice 2, it jumps to the message rather than displaying whatever tweets are in the dictionary. Am I not adding any tweets?
2. When doing choice 3, it displays the supposed message when there aren't any tweets -     `No tweets contained  <function Tweet.get_author at 0x02E20348> <function Tweet.get_text at 0x02E20390>`

So, I am guessing that I am not appending any tweets to the list. Am I correct?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "choice 2?"

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and try to improve your question, e.g. with a better title and explain why there is two python scripts and what the relationship between them, etc.

Comment: Please, can you better explain your problem?

Answer (score 0):

In your add method from twitter.py file:

```
def add(mytweets):

    author = input("\nWhat is your name? ")
    while True:
        text = input("what would you like to tweet? ")
        if len(text) > 140:
            print("\nTweets can only be 140 characters!")
            continue
        else:
            break




    entry = Tweet.Tweet(author, text)

    print("\nYour tweet has been saved!")
```

You are not adding the tweets to any dictionary or list, you are basically just reading user input and creating an instance of the Tweet class.

So, you need to add something like:

```
mytweets.update({author:text})
```